# Is an int the same as unsigned or signed?

Tags: c++

Is an int the same type as unsigned or signed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plain `int` is the same as `signed` is the same as `signed int`

Comment: Some (all?) compilers have a switch to change the default to unsigned. In MSVC, it's /J.

Comment: FYI The CCS compiler for Microchip PIC controllers is unsigned by default. Argh!

Comment: The /J compiler switch affects char, not int. "char" may or may not be signed. "char", "signed char" and "unsigned char" are always distinct types, whether or not "char" is signed.

Answer (score 12):

C++ Standard 3.9.1/2:

> There are four ***signed integer types***: “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, and “long int.” <...>

C++ Standard 3.9.1/3:

> For each of the signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (*but different*) ***unsigned integer type***:
>   “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, and “unsigned long
>   int,” <...>

So, `sizeof(int)` is equal to `sizeof(unsigned)`. But `boost::is_same< int, unsigned >::value` is false.

Answer (score 3):

`ints` are signed by default, as are `longs`.

So, `int`, `signed` and `signed int` are the same thing.

Similarly `long` and `signed long` are the same.

`chars` on the other hand, don't have a default.  Implementations can consider them signed or unsigned (many have a command line switch to choose).  `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are considered three distinct types for overload resolution, template instaniation and other places.

Comment: The last sentence is too restricted. It's not just overload resolution, it's everywhere. E.g. also as template arguments. Thus `std::vector<int>` is the same type as `std::vector<signed int>`, but `std::vector<char>` is **not** the same type as `std::vector<signed char>`

Answer (score 2):

`int`s are signed by default.

Answer (score 1):

`signed int` is the same as `int` and specifies an integer value that can have both positive and negative values.

`unsigned int` on the other hand can only have positive values, so the greatest positive value is much larger than that of a `signed int`.

Comment: Actually the *range* of values is exactly the same size, it's just shifted so that the minimum value is 0.